# Whitespace Between Tags in HAML

Tags: ruby, formatting, whitespace, haml

Is there a way to specify "pretty-print"-like formatting around HTML tags?  I want to be able to put whitespace between blocks of HTML, so this:

```
<!-- container -->
<div id='container'>
</div>
<!-- footer -->
<div id="footer">
</div>
<!-- analytics -->
...
```

...is converted to this:

```
<!-- container -->
<div id='container'>
</div>


<!-- footer -->
<div id="footer">
</div>


<!-- analytics -->
...
```

I know you can do comments with `/`, is there something like that for whitespace between tags?  Maybe something like this

```
/ container
#container
\
\
/ footer
#footer
:s
:s
/ analytics
```

Where the `\` or `:s` could be custom filters?

Or even something like `= space(10)` for 10 line breaks?  Or maybe even `~` by itself but that doesn't work.

Comment: My personal opinion on this is that generated HTML is not for the human to read, but for the machine, so whitespace shouldn't make any difference. For debugging the document structure Firebug/Web Inspector type tools are much more useful, and especially with HAML you shouldn't need to worry about the validity of the produced HTML anyway. Hence, why worry about it? As I said though, that's IMO and doesn't answer your question... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#container
- haml_concat("\n" * 5)
#footer
```

The `haml_concat` helper directly concatenates text onto the output buffer, without any sort of pre-processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can [evaluate Ruby block](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_) to insert additional newlines:

```
.main
  .container
    %p Something

  ~ "\n" * 5

  .footer
    %p Footer
```

This also uses `~` - [whitespace preservation](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#tilde).

Comment: I was trying that but it doesn't actually output the html with 5 lines between tags, just 1 :/. currently you'd have to have 5 ~, one on each line, which obscures everything too much.

Answer (score 0):

```
\#container  
= ('< br />'*5).html_safe 

\#footer
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote special filter for that kind of thing: https://gist.github.com/dmitry/6050231

To use is, you just need to add `:s`, like in your example:

```
#footer
:s
:s
/ analytics
```